# Find a continuous bijection from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Find a continuous bijection from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$.

I have solved the question for "Find a continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$". Moreover there is no such map.   But cannot solve if there is a continuous bijection from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$.

Please help.

Comment: There is no such function.

Comment: What you ask or claim is unclear.

Comment: You can pretty easily prove that if $f:(0,1]\to(0,1)$ is a continuous bijection, then so is its inverse $f^{-1}:(0,1)\to(0,1]$, but you already know such cannot exist

Comment: @AndreaMori I have edited.

Comment: You'd have to pick what to map 1 to, and then there'd be problems when looking at both sides of that image.

Comment: If there's no continuous bijection from $A$ to $B$, then there won't be a continuous bijection from $B$ to $A$, either, because they would be inverses of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $f:(0,1]\to (0,1)$ is bijective and continuous, then $f|_{(0,1)}:(0,1)\to (0,1)\setminus\{f(1)\}$ is continuous. However, continuous functions map connected spaces to connected spaces, ergo since $(0,1)$ is connected, $f((0,1))=(0,1)\setminus\{f(1)\}$ is connected - which is obviously not (it decomposes as $(0,f(1))\cup (f(1),1)$). Therefore there cannot exist such $f$.