# Continuous bijection from $(0,1]$ to $(0,1)$ on rational numbers.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, rational-numbers

Recently, I have been dealing with generalizing notions using the real numbers by [using the rationals instead.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604435/definition-of-closed-and-open-qanifolds-manifolds-over-mathbbq-can-a-q) A function $f\colon\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ is rational-continuous at a rational number $\alpha$ iff for any $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exists a corresponding $\delta$ based on $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon$ such that if $|\alpha-x| \leq \delta, |f(\alpha)-f(x)| \leq \varepsilon.$ Is there a "rational-continuous" bijection from the rationals in $(0,1]$ to the rationals in $(0,1)?$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599179/find-a-continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1

Comment: I don't know whether the "continuity" tag belongs here, since it isn't really about continuity...

Comment: Plus, the tag wiki gives intuition for what continuity means, which is totally untrue in this context (evidence: my Qanifolds question)

Comment: What does "rational-continuous" mean?

Comment: Thanks. Edited.

Comment: That doesn't really help me. What *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: I believe for any reasonable version of this question the answer is **yes** by a [back-and-forth argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#Application_to_densely_ordered_sets) - basically, abuse the heck out of the countability of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the fact that $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ have the same closure - but the details are tedious to write up.

Comment: Did you intentionally reverse $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$? If so, how does the accepted answer address your definition?

Comment: Thanks for telling me. Fixed.

Comment: OK, so this *is* the usual notion of continuity of a map defined on (a subset of) $\Bbb  Q$. I don't know why you objected to my adding the continuity tag.

Comment: The reason is that the tag wiki only provided an intuitive explanation, which is totally wrong in the case of rational numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f\colon (0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}\to (\pi/4,1+\pi/4)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ by:

$$f(t)=1+t,\qquad t<\pi/4,$$
$$ f(t)=t, \qquad t>\pi/4.$$

Then $f$ is continuous and bijective.

It remains to define a continuous bijective function $(\pi/4,1+\pi/4)\cap \mathbb{Q}\to (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

However this can be done piecewise linearly on intervals:

Let $a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ be an increasing sequence, with:$$
\lim_{n\to-\infty} a_n=\pi/4,\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1+\pi/4,$$
and let $b_n\in\mathbb{Q}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ be an increasing sequence, with:$$
\lim_{n\to-\infty} b_n=0,\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=1.$$

Then simply map each interval $[a_n,a_{n+1}]$ linearly to $[b_n,b_{n+1}]$.

Comment: What's the proof for the piecewise linear definition?

Comment: As far as I see, this would give (0,1].

Comment: ...and by accepting your answer, I achieved a reputation of exactly $\lfloor \pi \cdot 1000 \rfloor$.

Comment: That is appropriate.